# Display back button in fragment with Toolbar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-toolbar

I'm using fragment based navigation, each fragment has it's own toolbar.

When navigating to a fragment I want the back button to display in the toolbar.

I have overridden the OnCreateView method as follows:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   var view = this.BindingInflate(_fragmentId, null);
   _toolbar = view.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
   if (_toolbar != null)
   {
      ParentActivity.SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
      ParentActivity.SupportActionBar.Title = _title;
      ParentActivity.SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      _drawerToggle = new MvxActionBarDrawerToggle(
         Activity,
         (ParentActivity as MainView).DrawerLayout,
         _toolbar,
         Resource.String.drawer_open,
         Resource.String.drawer_close);

      (ParentActivity as MainView).DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
   }

   return view;
}
```

SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) should be changing the button to the back button, according to numerous other stack overflow answers, However this is not working as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: back button not shown]

I have checked that the SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) line is hit when I navigate to the fragment.

For reference I am using Xamarin with MvvmCross.

How do I make change the toolbar to the up/back button when using fragment based navigation?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

The DrawerToggle was somehow overriding the toolbar settings. Adding the following line fixes the problem.

```
_drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Xamarin. Try setting the indicator with **ParentActivity.SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);**. This might help.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect, it still shows the three horizontal lines.

Comment: The Title does change as expected just not the icon